# Jquery validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I am new In jquery created validation and calculation  using formula.I have created six input fields.created validation all fields.but when empty all fields click calculation red star symbol showing first two fields not showing remain four fields please help me friends

here my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function isNumber(evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function calculate() {

            var answer = 0;

            if (validate()) {

                var valueA = $("#valuea").val()

                var valueB = $("#valueb").val()

                var valueC = $("#valuec").val()

                var valueD = $("#valued").val()

                var valueE = $("#valuee").val()

                var valueF = $("#valuef").val()


                if (valueA && valueB && valueC && valueD && valueE && valueF) {
                    answer = ((parseFloat(valueB / valueA)) + (parseFloat(valueD / valueC)) + (parseFloat(valueF / valueE))) / 3;
                }
                else {

                    if (valueA && valueB && valueC && valueD)
                        answer = ((parseFloat(valueB / valueA)) + (parseFloat(valueD / valueC))) / 2;
                    else {
                        if (valueA && valueB && valueE && valueF)
                            answer = ((parseFloat(valueB / valueA)) + (parseFloat(valueF / valueE))) / 2;

                        else (valueA && valueB)
                        answer = ((parseFloat(valueB / valueA)));
                    }                   
                }
                if (parseFloat(answer) > .0238)
                    alert("Your Effective Rate = " + parseFloat(answer * 100).toFixed(2));
                else if (answer == 0)
                    alert("Your Effective Rate:0.00% ");
                else
                    alert("Oops, something has gone terribly wrong!Please attach at least 2 months of your most recent credit card processing statements and one of our specialists will respond within 24 hours with an accurate cost analysis");

            }
            return false;
        }
        function validate() {
            var status = false;

            var valueA = $("#valuea").val()

            var valueB = $("#valueb").val()

            var valueC = $("#valuec").val()

            var valueD = $("#valued").val()

            var valueE = $("#valuee").val()

            var valueF = $("#valuef").val()

            if (valueA) {
                $("#spana").hide();
                status = true;
            }
            else {
                $("#spana").show();

                status = false;
            }

            if (valueB) {
                status = true;
                $("#spanb").hide();
            }
            else {
                status = false;
                $("#spanb").show();
            }
            if (valueC && !valueD) {
                status = false;
                $("#spand").show();
                $("#spanc").hide();
            }
            if (!valueC && valueD) {
                status = false;
                $("#spanc").show();
                $("#spand").hide();
            }

            if (valueE && !valueF) {
                status = false;
                $("#spanf").show();
                $("#spane").hide();
            }
            if (!valueE && valueF) {
                status = false;
                $("#spane").show();
                $("#spanf").hide();
            }
            if (valueC && valueD) {
                $("#spand").hide();
                $("#spanc").hide();
                return true;
            }
            if (valueE && valueF) {
                status = true;
                $("#spane").hide();
                $("#spanf").hide();
            }           

            return status;

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <table class="calculator" border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1'
        class="table">
        <tr class="calcheading">
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                Whats your effective rate?
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="monthheading">
            <td colspan="2">
                <strong>Month 1</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow">
            <td>
                Total Sales, Including Amex
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type='text' name='valuea' id="valuea" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                    autocomplete="off" />
                <td align="center">
                    <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spana">*</span>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow2">
            <td>
                Total Fees, less any terminal or rental fees
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type='text' name='valueb' id="valueb" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                    autocomplete="off" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spanb">*</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="monthheading">
            <td colspan="2">
                <strong>Month 2</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow">
            <td>
                Total Sales, Including Amex
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type='text' name='valuec' id="valuec" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                    autocomplete="off" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spanc">*</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow2">
            <td>
                Total Fees, less any terminal or rental fees
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type='text' name='valued' id="valued" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                    autocomplete="off" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spand">*</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="monthheading">
            <td colspan="2">
                <strong>Month 3</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow">
            <td>
                Total Sales, Including Amex
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type='text' name='valuee' id="valuee" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                    autocomplete="off" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spane">*</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow2">
            <td>
                Total Fees, less any terminal or rental fees
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type='text' name='valuef' id="valuef" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                    autocomplete="off" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spanf">*</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="submit">
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <input type='submit' value='Calculate' onclick="return calculate();" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow">
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

calculation all working good.when leave fields empty click calculation show red star required first two column remain not showing help me friends

Comment: why don't you create a fiddle for this ? use www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the condition you have written for the valueC,valueD, valueE and valueF. You should continue as of valueA and valueA  for the remaining too, if you want to achieve the functionality as you are trying to.

But, My Suggestion is to Use http://jqueryvalidation.org/ Plugin for validating the elements. It is very handy to use and customize as required.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check you conditions. small logical mistakes in your conditions. for eg.

```
if (valueC && !valueD) {
            status = false;
            $("#spand").show();
            $("#spanc").hide();
        }
        if (!valueC && valueD) {
            status = false;
            $("#spanc").show();
            $("#spand").hide();
        }
```

This will check if either valuec or valued is empty. You are not checking for both empty. You need to add something like this

```
      if (!valueC && !valueD) {
            status = false;
            $("#spand").show();
            $("#spanc").hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother its not a good trick to make your code lengthy. You could achieve your goal by using each function. Below is an example of doing that. Please have a look.

```
function validate(){

 var formValidate = true;
    jQuery(form + " select," + form + " input").each(
            function (index) {
                var input = jQuery(this);

                    if (input.val() == "" ) {
                        input.addClass("error");
                        input.parent().next("td").fadeIn("slow");
                    }
                    else {
                        input.removeClass("error");
                        input.parent().next("td").fadeOut("slow");
                    }
                    if (input.hasClass('error')) {
                        if (formValidate == true) {
                            formValidate = false;
                        }
                    }

            }
    );

    if (formValidate == true) {

        return true;
    }
    else {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

exact solution to your answer is below please copy n paste then check.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="../jQuery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
return false;
}
return true;
}
function calculate() {

var answer = 0;
if (validate()) {
var valueA = $("#valuea").val()

var valueB = $("#valueb").val()

var valueC = $("#valuec").val()

var valueD = $("#valued").val()

var valueE = $("#valuee").val()

var valueF = $("#valuef").val()


if (valueA && valueB && valueC && valueD && valueE && valueF) {
answer = ((parseFloat(valueB / valueA)) + (parseFloat(valueD / valueC)) + (parseFloat(valueF / valueE))) / 3;
}
else {
if (valueA && valueB && valueC && valueD)
answer = ((parseFloat(valueB / valueA)) + (parseFloat(valueD / valueC))) / 2;
else {
if (valueA && valueB && valueE && valueF)
                        answer = ((parseFloat(valueB / valueA)) + (parseFloat(valueF / valueE))) / 2;

                    else (valueA && valueB)
                    answer = ((parseFloat(valueB / valueA)));
                }                   
            }
            if (parseFloat(answer) > .0238)
                alert("Your Effective Rate = " + parseFloat(answer * 100).toFixed(2));
            else if (answer == 0)
                alert("Your Effective Rate:0.00% ");
            else
                alert("Oops, something has gone terribly wrong!Please attach at least 2 months of your most recent credit card processing statements and one of our specialists will respond within 24 hours with an accurate cost analysis");

        }
        return false;
    }
    function validate() {
        var status = false;

        var valueA = $("#valuea").val()
        var valueB = $("#valueb").val()
        var valueC = $("#valuec").val()
        var valueD = $("#valued").val()
        var valueE = $("#valuee").val()
        var valueF = $("#valuef").val()

        if (valueA) {
            $("#spana").hide();
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#spana").show();
            status = false;
        }

        if (valueB) {
            status = true;
            $("#spanb").hide();
        }
        else {
            status = false;
            $("#spanb").show();
        }
        if (valueC && !valueD) {
            status = false;
            $("#spand").show();
            $("#spanc").hide();
        }
        if (!valueC && valueD) {
            status = false;
            $("#spanc").show();
            $("#spand").hide();
        }

        if (valueE && !valueF) {
            status = false;
            $("#spanf").show();
            $("#spane").hide();
        }
        if (!valueE && valueF) {
            status = false;
            $("#spane").show();
            $("#spanf").hide();
        }
        if (valueC && valueD) {
            $("#spand").hide();
            $("#spanc").hide();
            return true;
        }
        if (valueE && valueF) {
            status = true;
            $("#spane").hide();
            $("#spanf").hide();
        } 

        //change is here 
        //change status value as per your requirement
        if (!valueC && !valueD) {
            //status = false;
            $("#spand").show();
            $("#spanc").show();
        }

        if (!valueE && !valueF) {
            //status = false;
            $("#spanf").show();
            $("#spane").show();
        }


        return status;

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table class="calculator" border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
    <tr class="calcheading">
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            Whats your effective rate?
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="monthheading">
        <td colspan="2">
            <strong>Month 1</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>
            Total Sales, Including Amex
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type='text' name='valuea' id="valuea" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                autocomplete="off" /></td>
            <td align="center">
                <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spana">*</span>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow2">
        <td>
            Total Fees, less any terminal or rental fees
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type='text' name='valueb' id="valueb" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spanb">*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="monthheading">
        <td colspan="2">
            <strong>Month 2</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>
            Total Sales, Including Amex
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type='text' name='valuec' id="valuec" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spanc">*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow2">
        <td>
            Total Fees, less any terminal or rental fees
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type='text' name='valued' id="valued" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spand">*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="monthheading">
        <td colspan="2">
            <strong>Month 3</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td>
            Total Sales, Including Amex
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type='text' name='valuee' id="valuee" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spane">*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow2">
        <td>
            Total Fees, less any terminal or rental fees
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type='text' name='valuef' id="valuef" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"
                autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold; display: none;" id="spanf">*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="submit">
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <input type='submit' value='Calculate' onclick="return calculate();" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it in that way consider below validation method. 
**I assume what you want is to check the input fields are empty or not**. what you have done is still unclear to me.

To do a proper validation you need to identify and state what should be checked and how should they handled as well.

```
function validate() {
        var status = false;

        var valueA = $("#valuea").val();

        var valueB = $("#valueb").val();

        var valueC = $("#valuec").val();

        var valueD = $("#valued").val();

        var valueE = $("#valuee").val();

        var valueF = $("#valuef").val();

        if (valueA) {
            $("#spana").hide();
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#spana").show();
            status = false;
        }
        if (valueB) {
            $("#spanb").hide();
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#spanb").show();
            status = false;
        }
        if (valueC) {
            $("#spanc").hide();
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#spanc").show();
            status = false;
        }
        if (valueD) {
            $("#spand").hide();
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#spand").show();
            status = false;
        }
        if (valueE) {
            $("#spane").hide();
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#spane").show();
            status = false;
        }
        if (valueF) {
            $("#spanf").hide();
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#spanf").show();
            status = false;
        }


        return status;

    }
```

Comment: i have dont first two fields required after remain fields optional my fields accept Zero value also.if enter zero value any fields that time also need show red star required